# How to make a angucomplete-alt tag 'required' in a form

Tags: angularjs-directive, required

I am using angucomplete-alt in many places of my web application (in forms), but i cant make the autocomplete fields as a 'required' field, even thought i've used the 'field-required' attribute.

```
angucomplete-alt#sectorSuggested(field-required= true,placeholder='Search sectors', local-data='sectors', selected-object='onSectorSelected', search-fields='Sector', pause='300', minlength='1', title-field='Sector',input-class="form-control form-control-small", name='sector')
```

how do i make it required field, please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going off of the documentation and examples I can see [here](http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/), it looks like the attribute should be

`field-required="true"`

In the above example, his element looks like this:

```
<div angucomplete-alt="" id="ex8" placeholder="Search countries" pause="100" selected-object="countrySelected8" local-data="countries" search-fields="name" title-field="name" minlength="1" input-class="form-control form-control-small" match-class="highlight" field-required="true" class="ng-isolate-scope">
```

Additionally, if you have many required fields, his documentation states:

> Set custom class name for required. Unique class names need to be set
>   when you have multiple directives to validate

You can do this, using the `field-required-class` attribute.

Taken from [here](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt)

Comment: i tried enclosing the `true` in quotes , and yet its not a required field, i also tried the field-required-class= <unique class name>, and its still not working, am i missing something? thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can use `field-required = "true"`
and it should work fine.

Comment: @syed You should have voted the other answer as the correct one. It gave you two possible solutions: the first one is identical, the second one you did not try.

Comment: You should add "input-name" as well take a look at https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt/issues/196#issuecomment-175750330